# Tensorflow and image processing in Java

Tags: java, image, tensorflow

Are there some examples how to load freeze graph trained in python to Java and use it for image recognition (image as an input, example of converting Image into Tensor). I am looking for a way to use existing model in Java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [LabelImage.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java) example which uses Inception5h model to classify images.

Inception5h is the pre-trained model which you can download from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip).

Note : To run this java code in your IDE, you need to download 2 libraries

1. libtensorflow-1.10.1.jar
2. libtensorflow_jni-1.10.0.jar